# Webpack 5 - Asset Modules - png|jpg - Webpack Error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

I am using the latest version of webpack for my react project.

I am attempting to load png or jpgs. I was trying with the old "loader"s however I was still getting the "unexpected token" when trying to load an imported image.

I found from googling that Webpack 5 now uses Asset Modules to load assets now.

I've used the recommend module rule below:

```
 module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
```

However when I attempt to build, I get this error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0].type should be one of these:
"javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
 -> Module type to use for the module
```

I have been on this for the last 7hr hours with no luck. Any assistance would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to match images of different types.

```
{
   test: [/\.svg$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
   loader: "file-loader",
   options: {
       name: "asset/resource/[name].[ext]"
   }
}
```

make sure the path exists.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Double check whether both installed packages: `webpack` and `webpack-cli` are up-to-date.